# how can I download the previous version of PHP source code

Tags: php, download

hey guys，I want to download php 5.1.6's source code,but the PHP official site(http://php.net/downloads.php) only have 5.4 and 5.3 , so how can i download 5.1.6's source code 
thks

Answer (score 8):

You can download it at:

http://www.php.net/releases/

This goes way back to 3.0.18

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/php/php-src/tags
or
https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/PHP-5.1